# Firefox doesn't import all history from Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, history, migration, import

When importing history from Google Chrome 89.0.4389.90 to Firefox 86.0.1, the latter doesn't import all items. Only last month's history is there while I have been using Chrome for over a year.

How to import all items, without truncating to Firefox from Chrome ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the behaviour, open `about:config` in Firefox and change

- `browser.migrate.chrome.history.limit` to a large number like 1 million.
- `browser.migrate.chrome.history.maxAgeInDays` to something like 3650

Then do the import.